# Phonegap app for iOS without Phonegap Build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, command-line-interface

So I asked and answered the question [how to do Phonegap 3.0 without Phonegap Build][1]. Now my app is ready for iOS as well (I think) and it's time to start deploying and debugging for that platform.

The formal question: how can I add the iOS platform to a Phonegap 3.0 project?

Answer (score 8):

This answer is still in progress.

Goals I've achieved:

- Compiling the project in command line, then running on device or sim using xCode

Attempts failed:

- Compiling and running (device/sim) all from the command-line

---

**1. Creation**

I could easily add the iOS platform as described in the [docs' iOS Platform Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide_open_a_project_in_the_sdk).

Basically, if the project already exists because you did Android first, this is how you set up the iOS app structure.

```
$ add platform ios
```

Then you should add files to the main /www folder if you didn't already have them from your Android work. Then this takes care of creating the app in debug form:

```
$ cordova prepare //Creates all the necessary source filed
$ cordova compile  //Creates an ipa file

//Alternatively, do both in one go with cordova build
```

---

**2. Deploying to device**

But it is completely unclear how to use the command line interface to actually deploy the test app to device or emulator.

When you attach a physical iOS device, and simply try this from the main project folder...

```
$ cordova run ios
```

You get a pretty clear answer:

```
[Error: An error occurred while running the ios project. Targeting a device is not supported currently.
```

]

So I've resigned myself that for device testing, I must still use xCode. No biggie. However, xCode cannot "refresh" the project by itself after you've updated your files, so in between deploys you must go back to the command-line to recompile the iOS app.

Strangely, when I update my code, I do need to use "cordova run ios" (even with the above error) in order for the the /platforms/ios/www folder to be updated. So this is what works and does not work:

```
$ cordova run ios 
//Rebuilds the app with main /www files successfully,
//then tries to deploy to device and fails in that.

$ cordova prepare ios
//Does not rebuild with main /www files
//(Also does not deploy but that is not its intended function)
```

And remember that you also need to clean your xCode project in between runs. So the sequence is:

1. Previous run
2. Edit your code
3. In console, do: cordova run ios
4. In xCode, Menu bar > Product > Clean product
5. in xCode, Run

---

**3. Deploying to emulator**

Still, "deploying to device is not possible" begs the question "What about emulator?"...

The docs page on the 3.0 command-line interface mentions you should enter the command

```
$ /path/to/my_new_project/cordova/run
```

This had me all confused. What kind of path is that? From where are you supposed to run it? Is it a nice way of providing a command you can run from anywhere? Why force me to enter my annoyingly long project path for each command?

Confusingly, the run command doesn't work if you actually go to the "platforms/ios/cordova" directory where the run executable is located.

The trick is to be one directory lower, i.e. at the /platforms/ios subfolder of your Cordova app project. There you type "cordova/run". Then in my case it starts building.

---

**4. Install "ios-sim"**

But that was not the end of it. I subsequently get an unanticipated error about "ios-sim" not being installed.

```
[...]
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Error: ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.5 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim into your path. Or 'brew install ios-sim' using homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/
```

Fortunately that project webpage has adequate documentation on how to install. However, even after adding the ios-sim directory to my $PATH, when I want to emulate I get the following error.

```
$ cordova emulate ios
[TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]
```

This is where I am currently stuck. My path looks exactly like this (all in one line):

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/adt-bundle/
sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/adt-bundle/sdk
/tools:%JAVA_HOME%\bin%ANT_HOME%\bin:"/Users/
cool/Library/Developer/iossim"
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with and without doublequotes, and I've even renamed the ios-sim directory to iossim in case the hyphen was the problem. No effect.

So no simulator for now.

**5. Install to iOS App Store**

This is the point where Phonegap really leaves you out in the woods. Maybe because they want you to use their paid app publishing service, but also because the process of publishing an iOS app is basically soemthing you do using xCode, iOS Developer Portal, and iTunes Connect.

So here that goes:

You need to have all the right certificates and profiles for your app (yes, it's a bunch of incomprehensible virtual documents that all require each other, Apple is like the Soviet Union of app stores).

You request those certificates and profiles in the iOS Developer Portal, save them to disk, then double-click them so that xCode knows you have them and will include them in your app.

This is the [docs page for xCode 4](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuideXcode4/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013500) on how to publish your app.

The most counter-intuitive bit is that in order to publish your app, you first have to create an archive of it in xCode (Open your project in xCode > menu bar > Product > Archive).

When the archive is made, you will see it in the Organizer view under the Archives tab. There should be two buttons: Validate and Distribute. Validate checks and includes all your profiles and certificates in the app, and it also checks for errors like a wrong version number.

Distribute does what it says: it sumbits the app to the App Store.

Congratulations! (Now wait five days)